# using 8 AA or Ni-MH batteries instead of one 12V 23A type battery to power a remote receiver

Tags: batteries, wireless, 12v, remote-control

Sorry for the novice question, but I am thinking there should be a simple solution.  I work as a magician and purchased an effect where a snake puppet in a basket goes up and down on a battery powered telescoping linear actuator.  It's operated by a wireless remote.  Here is what I know, the two button remote (up and down buttons) uses a 12V 23A type battery.  The receiver for the remote (in the the snake basket) also uses a 12V 23A type battery.  There is an on/off switch in the basket to turn the remote receiver off.  Here is what I think I know-the motor that drives the snake up and down must be 18V-I am pretty sure it is powered by 2 9V batteries.
The problem is that 12V 23A battery that supplies power to the receiver just doesn't last-even with keeping the switch off, it get through about 2-3 shows, maybe 15 up and down motions and the battery quits-once it drains down to ~11.5V-it's done and that snake ain't moving.  Any ideas on a better solution to power the remote receiver?  Is there a better choice of battery?  There is lots of space in the basket so the small footprint of the 12V 23A battery is not important.  Here is my concern, 8 AA batteries will generate a lot more current than the 12V 23A-will the extra current blow the remote?  Or will a rechargeable 12V 600mA NiMH battery be the most robust option? thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1):

The 8 AA cells can produce a lot more current than the 23A battery, but the receiver will only draw the current that it requires - the larger battery will not force excessive currrent into the receiver, providing it provides the correct voltage.

Comment: True enough, but the mechanism will also probably respond a good deal faster than the poster is accustomed to. Which may to may not be to his taste.

Comment: thank you Peter-really helpful-so using 8 AA batteries should last longer overall-will probably go with a rechargeable 12V NiMH 600mA battery. thank you again!